# Make .well-known directory visible in Express 4

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, https, certbot

This took me a while to figure out, so I figure I'd leave some instructions on how I got it done in case someone else runs into the same problems.

I needed to allow directory access to the .well-known directory in Express to be able to use certbot to generate SSL certificates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install the serve-index package from npm

```
npm install serve-index
```

Import it

```
var serveIndex = require('serve-index');
```

Then declare the middleware

```
app.use('/.well-known', express.static('.well-known'), serveIndex('.well-known'));
```

Comment: It is unclear whether this is needed in order to be able to load the files themselves, or just to get some sort of directory listing? I am currently unable to serve /.well-known/foo.bar from my Expressjs server, and I’m not getting this to work…

Comment: @HeinHaraldsonBerg this was a couple years ago. I'd now strongly recommend using Nginx as your web server instead of node.js itself. Let's encrypt has built in support for nginx and is it considered a stable, secure web server. So serve your nodejs app on port 3000, then run nginx to proxy the node server from port 3000 to port 80. Then install nginx and it will automatically configure https over port 443 for you.